# Passing JSON Object into SOAP Parameters, returns null?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc-3, soap

New to SOAP, and I am having a problem passing in a JSON Object.

The webservice is returning an error saying that it contains nothing (Null) My code is below.

```
$params = json_encode(array(
    'AuthCode'      => $authCode,
    'FirstName'         => $firstname,
    'LastName'      => $lastname,
    'Email'             => $email,
    'Telephone'         => $telephone,
    'Country'       => $country
));

$data = array (
    'jsonObject' => $params
);

$client = new SoapClient($serviceURL, array (
    "trace"         => 1,
    "exceptions"        => 0,
    "encoding"      => 'UTF-8',
    "soap_version"  => SOAP_1_1
));

$res = $client->CreateUser(array('parameters' => $data));
```

We have set up for the service to check if there is valid data, and it appears there is none, so it returns NULL.

Have I constructed my parameters correctly?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: try changing the $res = $client->CreateUser(array('parameters' => $data));
with

$res = $client->CreateUser(array('parameters' => $params));

since the server would be looking json encoded data in parameter and you are sending an array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Arfeen. It set us on the right track. Turns out we were able to place the JSON object directly in and it worked.

Comment: so would it be ethical if I put my answer below and you accept that ? :)

Comment: It wasnt really a 100% solution was it ;) I will give both your posts up-votes however :)